# Use Apple Touch ID for login with external database

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id

I have an iOS application made in Swift, which is a little social network. User can connect with login/password which I save on a database on a private server. I would like to implement TouchID to help them login faster. However, my users' account are not linked to their Apple ID.

```
// Touch ID button has been clicked
func touchIDButtonClicked() {
    print("touchIDButtonClicked");

    //Is Touch ID hardware available & configured?
    if(authContext.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error:&error))
    {
        //Perform Touch ID auth
        authContext.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Connect to the network with your fingertips", reply: {(wasSuccessful:Bool, error:NSError?) in

            if(wasSuccessful)
            {
                //User authenticated
                print("OK");
                // Log the user
            }
            else
            {
                //There are a few reasons why it can fail, we'll write them out to the user in the label
                print("NO");
               // Tell the user to use his password
            }

        })

    }
}
```

I'm looking for a concept solution more than a technical one. I've already research TouchID. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

given that the username is unique in your db you should trust TouchId and login by username only ... by the way , that's how my homebanking app works  al least for low risk,not payments, functionalities

After some thinking i realize it is not sure at all until you do not implement also some additional schema mechanisms to be sure that login is coming from your app

A good solution could be use identifierForVendor to get a strong association between username , app and device, by storing it in the db and check it back while logging in

Comment: But here is a problem : User1 have his fingerprint on his phone. User1 can connect with touchID + username. If User1 knows User2 username, he can access User2 account no ? I have no link between the fingerprint and the username in my database.

Comment: understand , but the fact is there is not information returned from TOuchID at all , just YES / NO ...

Comment: consider using identifierForVendor ... that can be used ahead to make a strong association between a username and a given device and can be stored in your db to be check at login

Answer (score 6):

Touch ID does not identify a person (it cannot tell you if it's user 1 or user 2). It authenticates a person (the owner of the phone).

So you cannot use Touch ID alone to login. What you can use it for, is avoiding entering the same credentials.

So it would work like this:

1. The first time, as for user Id and password, and do your usual login
2. Ask if the user would like to use Touch Id for future access. If so, securely store the user Id and password (or, better, a token which references the user).
3. Then, on a subsequent use of the app, instead of asking for user Id and password, ask just for Touch ID, and re-use the saved credentials if it's OK. Otherwise go back to 1.